# How to preserve ancient Hindu culture and traditions in modern days?

Tags: shiva, scripture, history

How to preserve ancient Hindu culture and traditions in modern days? What steps should be taken to preserve the culture by children, adults and old aged people?

Comment: I think proper Introduction is the first step

Comment: I'm guessing, going by your name 'Trivedi', it means a person who has learned 3 vedas. If you're a brahmin and your parents/grandparents learned Vedas, then it is part of your duty to do same. that is your 'culture'. if you do it, the culture is preserved. if you don't, the culture is lost. simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the primary needs for Vedic culture  (वैदिक धर्म) / Sanatan Dharma  (सनातन धर्म) right now, especially in places like Modern India, is the  preservation, protection, promotion and perpetuation of its existence.

**Preservation-:** 
Chieldren, adults, senior citizens have to work in ways to preserve the culture to make sure it will also be around over the long term so others can learn about it, take advantage of its wisdom, and even follow it for their own spiritual progress. This may include, but not limited to, such things as:

1. Preserve the great and ancient Vedic texts,
2. Preserve the main yoga systems, the dharmas that lead to God,
3. Preserve the temples and let them be freely maintained by those Hindus and devotees who are most sincere and qualified,
4. Distribute this literature for colleges, schools, personal homes, so it can spread,
5. Educate people in this knowledge, especially the youth so they are aware of it and know it,
6. Practice the traditions, such as the holidays and spiritual paths in everyday life.

   **PROTECTION-:**

   Even if we do what we can to preserve the tradition, it may also come under attack in many ways. So we have to help protect it by:
7. Overcoming negative impressions that people may try to use to unnecessarily criticize or demean it,
8. Be on guard for negative press in newspapers or television, and work to correct it,
9. Watch for the use of devious ways and false statements that are said to convert people from the Vedic path to some other religion,

**PROMOTION: -**

Promotion of some form is a must. And the Vedic tradition is one of the most profound and dynamic cultures the world has ever seen. Therefore, there is a great need to let others know about it. This does not mean that you have to be in a conversion campaign, but you can certainly share what you know of it. Many people are looking for deeper levels of spirituality, but they do not know where to look, or they do not know the depth of what the Vedic path or its knowledge has to offer. Someone has to be willing to tell them. In fact, we all should be willing. Therefore:

1. Everyone can be a Vedic Ambassador to simply share with other seekers the ways the Vedic culture has helped them and what they have gotten out of it, the difference it has made in their life,
2. Promote it as a spiritual path that can help solve many of the world’s problems,
3. Distribute the simpler portions of the Vedic texts, such as Bhagavad-gita, or various forms of introductory literature that can introduce and easily explain what the Vedic path is .
4. Offer classes on yoga and Vedic philosophy for the same reason,
5. And hold programs wherein the youth can also be a part of it and practice it,
6. Arrange for radio or even cable TV programs so everyone can learn from it or stay connected.

**PERPETUATION:**

Is why we do all of the above. How can we keep Vedic culture a flourishing and dynamic path? By doing all of the above, and providing the means to show people how to practice it. Without the preservation, protection, and promotion of Vedic culture, it cannot be perpetuated. This is where such things as the following can be helpful:

1. Establish and maintain temples that help uphold and show how to practice the Vedic traditions.
2. Hold classes and study groups, either at temples or at homes, wherein people get together to comfortably converse on various topics of the Vedic texts to help everyone understand it and how deep or practical it is, and then invite friends to join,

   3)     There are many other points that can be listed. But the main issue is that we have to work to keep the Vedic culture very much alive and available for everyone. It is what I call the "last bastion of deep spiritual truth." If this should ever disappear, the world will never know what it has lost.
   4) Some people may say that it is an eternal religion, Sanatana-dharma, so it will never fade away. But have they really read the Bhagavad-gita, wherein Lord Krishna explains that one of the reasons why He appeared was to re-establish the Vedic Dharma, which had become lost?

   **Lord Krishna says,** "I instructed this imperishable science of yoga to the sun-god, Vivasvan, and Vivasvan instructed it to Manu, the father of mankind, and Manu in turn instructed it to Iksvaku. This supreme science was thus received through the chain of disciplic succession, and the saintly kings understood it in that way. But in course of time the succession was broken, and therefore the science as it is appears to be lost. That very ancient science of the relationship with the Supreme is today told by Me to you because you are My devotee as well as My friend; therefore you can understand the transcendental mystery of this science." (Bg.4.1-3) श्री. भगवद गीता

   So, yes, it is eternal but can disappear from the face of the     earth, and does at times. It is up to those of us who are serious and sincere to make sure that it can continue being a practical spiritual culture far into the future by helping it

सर्वेपि सुखिनः सन्तु सर्वे सन्तु निरामयः।
सर्वे भद्राणि पश्यन्तु मा कश्चिद्दुःखभाग्भवेत् ।।

ॐ शांतिः शांतिः शांतिः

Source material is taken from - Preservation, Protection, Promotion and Perpetuation of Vedic Culture

by Stephen Knapp

Comment: Nice answer!... but I think the last Sanskrit quotation you used is "सर्वे भवन्तु सुखिनः
सर्वे सन्तु निरामयाः ।
सर्वे भद्राणि पश्यन्तु
मा कश्चिद्दुःखभाग्भवेत् ।
ॐ शान्तिः शान्तिः शान्तिः ॥".... I don't know whether variant version you have used exists or not...

Comment: @  Tezz hi , You are right their are variants , the shloka i have used is from my childhood.  I dont know weather it is in general use or not , but the central theme and marvalous meaning is same.  Well thanks for pointing  :)